# How to do Multi label classification or Multi class classification of the below problem? Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, logistic-regression

My original data looks like this.

```
    id  season   home_team  away_team  home_goals  away_goals result winner
 0  0   2006-07  Shu        Liv        1           1          D      NaN
 1  1   2006-07  Ars        Avl        1           1          D      NaN
 2  2   2006-07  Eve        Wat        2           1          H      Eve
 3  3   2006-07  New        Wig        2           1          H      New
 4  4   2006-07  Por        Bla        3           0          H      Por
```

The purpose is to build a model that predicts
i.e.

```
Home Team Win 55%

Draw          13%

Away Team Win 32%
```

I Selected these 3 columns and label encoded them

```
home_team, away_team, winner
```

Then I created these new classes/lables.

```
df.loc[df["winner"]==df["home_team"],"home_team_win"]=1
df.loc[df["winner"]!=df["home_team"],"home_team_win"]=0

df.loc[df["result"]=='D',"draw"]=1
df.loc[df["result"]!='D',"draw"]=0

df.loc[df["winner"]==df["away_team"],"away_team_win"]=1
df.loc[df["winner"]!=df["away_team"],"away_team_win"]=0
```

Now the encoded data is looking like this,

```
    home_team   away_team   home_team_win   away_team_win   draw
0   28          19          0               0               1
1   1           2           0               0               1
2   14          34          1               0               0
3   23          37          1               0               0
4   25          4           1               0               0
```

Initially, I used the code below for a single label **'home_team_win'** and it worked fine, but it doesn't support multi classes/labels.

```
X = prediction_df.drop(['home_team_win'] ,axis=1)

y = prediction_df['home_team_win']

logReg=LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs')

rfe = RFE(logReg, 20)

rfe = rfe.fit(X, y.values.ravel())
```

How to do Multi label classification or Multi class classification of this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The target binary variables `home_team_win`, `away_team_win`, and `draw` are mutually exclusive. It does not seem to be a good idea to use multi-label methods in this problem, since, in general, they are designed to exploit dependencies among labels, which is nonexistent in this dataset.

I suggest modelling it as a multi-class problem in its most common form, where there is a single column with three classes: 0,1, and 2 (representing home_team_loss, draw, away_team_win).
Many implementations of classifiers in scikit-learn can work directly in this manner. Logistic Regression is one of them:

```py
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

logReg=LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs', multi_class='ovr')
logReg.fit(X,Y)
logReg.predict_proba(X)
```

This code will output the desired probabilities for each class of each row of `X`.
In particular, this code trains one Logistic Regression for each class separately (this is what the `multi_class='ovr'` parameter do).

Take a look at https://scikit-learn.org/stable/supervised_learning.html for other classifiers that directly work in this multi-class dataset form that I suggested.